# Trying to localise a jQuery mobile datepicker input

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile datepicker (like the one [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html)), using `<input type="date" />` which needs to be able to display the date in an appropriate format, depending on the locale.

By default, the datepicker calendar displays in the date in English-UK style format `(dd-mm-yyyy)`. Occasionally, the service will have users in the US, and so would like the display to be in US format `(mm-dd-yyyy)`.

The locale is defined in the config of the website, using the `globalization culture` attribute.
Ideally, the datepicker needs to respond to the locale setting in the config, rather than the user's settings.

So, this isn't a case of languages, etc. Simply the formatting in the input area once a date has been picked and displayed to the user.
Setting the culture in the config works perfectly to format date strings elsewhere on the website, when displayed as a string, owing to some localisation functions. It's only in the datepicker that this is an issue.

EDIT: So, the question is - is it possible to change the format that the datepicker input displays the date in?

EDIT 2: After looking around a little bit more, it seems that the date format is determined by the user's local settings, and cannot be overridden. Is that definitely the case? 
If so, is there any way I can test this functionality out? I have tried changing my local settings to US, but have so far seen no changes to output. If I know it successfully works in that way, it may be sufficient to run with that.

EDIT 3: I have now been able to successfully test that formatting changes when local system settings are changed. It should be fine to go with that.
Thanks!

Comment: Oops, probably should have made that clearer. Added in an edit now.

Answer (score 2):

Studying the code a little (ok, not little, but a lot!), I was able to solve the problem with this code:

```
/* Brazilian initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Leonildo Costa Silva (leocsilva@gmail.com). */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
        closeText: 'Fechar',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Anterior',
        nextText: 'Pr&oacute;ximo&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Hoje',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Mar&ccedil;o','Abril','Maio','Junho',
        'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Ter&ccedil;a-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sabado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    $.mobile.date.prototype._setOptions($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    $(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker('destroy');
    $(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker();
});
```

The important and aditional part of the code (which does the magic) above is this:

```
    $.mobile.date.prototype._setOptions($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    $(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker('destroy');
    $(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker();
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't figure it out myself!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/) data picker up to JQM version 1.1 then answer is no, you can change ot in its js file but not dynamically.

But take a look at [this](http://mobiscroll.com/) date picker. I have tested it on my android/iphone app and it works just fine and it can be changed dynamically on the fly.

There is also a [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) but I don't have experience with it, it caused me some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a better solution. Instead of this:

```
$.mobile.date.prototype._setOptions($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
$(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker('destroy');
$(":jqmData(role='date')").datepicker();
```

You can only disable the async loading inserting a "defer" attribute in the script call. For example:

```
            <script src="/includes/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/layout_mobile/js/jquery-ui/datepicker.js" defer></script>
            <script src="/layout_mobile/js/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js" defer></script>
            <script src="/layout_mobile/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js" defer></script>
```